# Error when cleaning Windows recycle-bin with Clear-RecycleBin

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, powershell-5.0

I use this to clear the recycle bin of Windows:

```
powershell -command "& {Clear-RecycleBin -force}"
```

or even simpler

```
powershell Clear-RecycleBin -force
```

The command appears to work, but there's an error shown ("the system cannot find the file specified")

```
Clear-RecycleBin : Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Clear-RecycleBin -force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (RecycleBin:String) [Clear-RecycleBin], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToClearRecycleBin,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ClearRecycleBinCommand
```

As it seems, I could prevent the error with the additional parameter "-ErrorAction:Ignore". But I'd like to know what's wrong or why the error occurs in the first place. Any idea?

Comment: You need to translate the error for us

Comment: Sure - it's "file not found", or more detailed "the system cannot find the file specified" in "line:1, char:1".

Comment: Whats wrong with just using 'Clear-RecycleBin' or 'Clear-RecycleBin -Force' where are you running the command from?

Comment: @Antony: It's meant to be a custom command from inside a file manager (TC). But it behaves the same when called from cmd.exe.

Comment: Duh! I know what it is. Your question just doesn't say from cmd but does say powershell so why not call it in powershell.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in PowerShell 5. In PowerShell Core 7 this works without error message.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error, but it wasn't working (recycle bin not cleared). Sometimes the old school workarounds work best.

```
echo y | powershell Clear-RecycleBin
```

Comment: Same problem here - and it's language-dependent

Answer (score 0):

This site shows that there is a problem with PowerShell.

[PowerShell Error](https://serverfault.com/questions/822514/clear-recyclebin-on-remote-computer-fails)

I implemented the answer of above link in my script and it works.  Cleans the Recycle Bin without popping the error.  This is just a Band Aid for the actually problem.